# How to configure setter and getter name convention in Jackson for a particular class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, getter-setter, jackson-databind

There is a class with custom naming of getters and setters. Here they have no "get" or "set" prefix.

This special configuration is needed for only one class, not globally.

> I see a discussion in Jackson development thread mentioning `@JsonPOJO` annotation exactly for this purpose,
> but I don't find it in the latest version (`v2.13`) of Jackson.
>
> - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2674,
> - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1325

How to express the intention "use setters with names exactly as fields in JSON"?

The same as the following, but in a more concise way **without** putting `@JsonProperty` or `@JsonSetter` for every setter:

```
class MyModel{
  private String first;
  private int second;

  public String first(){
    return this.first;
  }

  @JsonProperty("first")
  public void first(String value){
    this.first = value;
  }

  public int second(){
    return this.second;
  }

  @JsonProperty("second")
  public void second(int value){
    this.second = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default accessor naming strategy as shown below.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

public class CustomPropertyNaming{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        try{
            /* ObjectMapper instance configuration:
             * (a) Override the default accessor naming strategy
             * (b) Set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false to avoid looking for other method names as properties (eg, toString()).
             * (c) Set REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS to true to handle 'toString()' being construed as a property getter */
            ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
            m.setAccessorNaming( new DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy.Provider().withGetterPrefix( "" ).withSetterPrefix( "" ) );
            m.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );
            m.configure( MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true );
            
            /* Serialization */
            String json = m.writeValueAsString( MyModel.of( "ONE", 2 ) );
            System.out.println( "Serialized: " + json );
            
            /* Deserialization */
            MyModel mm = m.readValue( json, MyModel.class );
            System.out.println( "Deserialized: " + mm );
        }
        catch( JsonProcessingException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of") @ToString
    private static class MyModel{
        private String first;
        private int second;

        public String first(){
            return this.first;
        }

        public void first( String value ){
            this.first = value;
        }

        public int second(){
            return this.second;
        }

        public void second( int value ){
            this.second = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Output from running the above class

```
Serialized: {"first":"ONE","second":2}
Deserialized: CustomPropertyNaming.MyModel(first=ONE, second=2)
```

(I have used Lombok on `MyModel`. You may have your constructors and `toString()`.)

A couple of points about this solution.

- Since the property names and accessor names are now same, Jackson tends to consider every zero-arg method as a getter and every one-arg method as setter. This needs to be handled. The way I have done here is by adding a couple configurations explained in the code comments.
- `DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy.Provider` has some other configurability that you may want to explore.

Comment: Thank you Kumar. The problem is this is required "for only one class, not globally" as mentioned in the question. I would like to have an annotation changing deserialization of a particular class.

Comment: Hi @diziaq, (a) **"for only one class, not globally":** As shown in the code, an `ObjectMapper` can be created just for this class (and maybe cached and reused). (b) **Annotation:** I couldn't find any Jackson annotation for this purpose