# @Accessors(fluent = true) does not work with Jakson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, lombok

In Spring boot application with Lombok, I have pojo class  `AccountDTO`

```
@Data
@Builder
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class AccountDTO  implements Serializable {
    private String identification;
}
```

My project compiles fine. However, it throws an exception in its execution

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class AccountDTO  and no properties discovered to create
> BeanSerializer

if I removed the annotation `@Accessors(fluent = true)`, then it will work fine without any problems.

How can i make `Lombok` `@Accessors(fluent = true)` and `Jackson` work together ?

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70134597/how-to-configure-setter-and-getter-name-convention-in-jackson-for-a-particular-c

Comment: @Sam, What about @Accessors(fluent = true) annotation? your link doesn't mention anything about it.

Comment: @MeladBasilius try to use on class level the annotation `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)`. This would allow Jackson to access those properties through reflection as the custom setter names provided by `fluent = true` are not understood by jackson

Comment: I haven't looked into the problem, so I'm just guessing here. I suspect Jackson expects getters to be named getXyz. If not, then you will have problems like yours. The article I linked shows a way of making Jackson understand getters following other patterns.

Comment: Another option is to annotate the fields with `@JsonProperty`, although the class level annotation mentioned above probably is better for many fields.

Comment: @MeladBasilius Please also try with `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")` . If this is working I can explain why

Comment: Does not work with `@Jacksonized` either. i.e The combination of `@Accessors(fluent = true)`, `@Data` (or `@Value`), `@Builder` and `@Jacksonized` does not work. Removing the `Accessor` notation allows the serialization to succeed but loses the fluency. Interestingly the **de**serialization works just fine with these annotations.

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled on this question recently while encountering the same problem and the solution for me was to add an explicit `@JsonProperty` annotation on the getter generated by Lombok using:
`@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonProperty))`.

In your case, the class would look like this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonProperty))
public class AccountDTO  implements Serializable {
    private String identification;
}
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: Note, that instead of `@Accessors(fluent = true)` you can set `lombok.accessors.fluent = true` in your `lombok.config` file